# visual studio intellisense error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
        friend Test<T> & operator * (T lhs, const Test<T> & rhs) {
            Test<T> r(rhs);
//              return r *= lhs;
        }
}
```

> 4  IntelliSense: identifier "T" is undefined

Why is `T` defined on line 3 but not line 4? I mean I guess it's not a real error just an intellisense error... It works anyway but is there something wrong? Can I fix it? Or remove the red squiggles somehow?

I am using visual studio 2010. I wonder if this happens in other versions as well?

Comment: Within the friend, you should be able to use `Test` instead of `Test<T>`. But i wouldn't: This isn't an error on your part; it's an intellisense bug, so i would rather send a bug report to MS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense shows `T` as undefined because it is a generic template type. Depending on how you instantiate the class, `T` will be a different type. For example if you have `Test<int> A`, `T` is of type `int`, but if you call `Test<string> A`, `T` is of type `string` for that class and it's methods.

Comment: ok but what you said applies to line 3 as well.. yet i get no error there

this only happens in friend

Comment: i think it's because of friend, it doesn't use any private members it's just friend to group it with rest of the operator overloads... but if i make it seperate from the class i don't get the 'error'

    template <typename T>
    class Test {
    }

    template <typename T>
    Vector3<T> & operator * (T lhs, const Vector3<T> & rhs) {
     Vector3<T> r(rhs);
     return r *= lhs;
    }

does it matter? better to group it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be getting confused by having the definition inside the class.  So changing your code to:

```
template <typename T>
class Test {

    friend Test<T> & operator * (T lhs, const Test<T> & rhs);
};

template <typename T>
Test<T> & operator * (T lhs, const Test<T> & rhs) {
    Test<T> r(rhs);
}
```

makes the problem go away.

This appears to be a bug in the compiler your code should be legal based on my reading of the spec (specifically 11.4/5).